# Django NOT NULL constraint failed: product_product.price

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am learning Django, and is following this online tutorial for creating forms. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6oOHlcHkX2U&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzTD1BD1aWNxS2Ep06vIkaeW&index=23. Upon rendering in browser, I receive NOT NULL constraint failed: product_product.price.

In my models.py I have

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = False, blank = False)
    description = models.TextField(null = True, blank = True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=0, max_digits = 10)
    active = models.BooleanField(default = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

In my views.py under the same app I have

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ProductForm

# Create your views here.

def productCreateView(request):
    form = ProductForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid:
        print('form is valid now to saving')
        print('\n\n')
        form.save()

    context = {'form' : form}

    return render(request, '../templates/product_create.html', context=context)
```

I have tried to

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

when I tried to modify my price in my models.py e.g. by stating

```
price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=0, max_digits = 10, blank = False, null = False)
```

Each time it says that there is nothing to migrate.

For the sake of learning, can anybody tell me what I am missing?

My complete error messages looks like below

```
[09/Mar/2020 23:24:41] "GET /create HTTP/1.1" 301 0
form is valid now to saving



Internal Server Error: /create/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\dimsumshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python\dimsumshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: product_product.price

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\dimsumshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python\dimsumshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python\dimsumshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\dimsumshop\shop\product\views.py", line 11, in productCreateView
    form.save()
  File "C:\Python\dimsumshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 459, in save
    self.instance.save()
  File "C:\Python\dimsumshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 746, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Python\dimsumshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 784, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "C:\Python\dimsumshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 887, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Python\dimsumshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 926, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw,
  File "C:\Python\dimsumshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\dimsumshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Python\dimsumshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1391, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python\dimsumshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python\dimsumshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Python\dimsumshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Python\dimsumshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python\dimsumshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Python\dimsumshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python\dimsumshop\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: product_product.price
[09/Mar/2020 23:24:41] "GET /create/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145386
```

Comment: Replace `form.is_valid` with `form.is_valid()`.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. Can you make it as an answer, so we can get the thread closed?

Answer (score 0):

Replace form.is_valid with form.is_valid() as proposed by Willem Van Onsem is the answer! Thanks!